# Ill-matched Font Size in Reputation Diagram

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

The user profile features a diagram which shows the curve of "reputation vs. time". Here's a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the font size is ill-matched. At first glance, I thought larger font sizes indicate questions/answers generating more rep, but a closer look revealed that this is not the case.

Comment: The difference is that the bigger one is the questions you've asked, the smaller one is the questions you've answered. I think the fundamental reasons may be the same as the post of mine: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/799/1800, the designer may use the same font module for the entire site.

Comment: Thanks Hsien-Chih. It seems so! Yet I think this is not intuitive. Maybe using colors or icons, or at least a legend helps.

Comment: Is this problem resolved? I still see questions having a much larger font than answers on the reputation page.

Comment: This is not resolved.

Comment: I asked Suresh to tag it as `status-completed`, since as per Hsien-Chih, it is not a bug but the site feature: the bigger one is the questions you've asked, the smaller one is the questions you've answered.

Comment: Maybe it does not qualify as a bug, but it is a weird feature, in my opinion, though.

Comment: If this is not going to be fixed, then it should be [status-bydesign] instead of [status-completed].

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: If so, please flag it for tag correction.

Comment: “If so, please flag it for tag correction.”  Done.

Answer (score 4):

I would like the moderators to reconsider the decision [status-bydesign].  In my opinion, distinguishing questions and answers by font size is unintuitive, and it might even be an unintentional result of the complicated style sheet.  That it is unintuitive is also indicated by this very question where Sadeq could not figure out why they were rendered in different sizes at the time he posted it.

Comment: Yeah, in the 2nd comment (below the OP), I said "this is not intuitive."

Comment: @Sadeq: I was not sure if you still consider it as unintuitive.  Your comments suggested me that you decided not to argue for the change.

Comment: I consider it unintuitive, but Hsien-Chih's comment ensured me it's not a bug. And since no comment/change whatsoever appeared in the past few days, I thought it was decided upon. Anyway, I thank you for bringing up the issue again. The comment above was to support your view.

Comment: @Sadeq: I still consider this as a bug, but maybe we merely use the word “bug” in slightly different ways.  And thanks for the explanation, I was wondering what your intent of your comment was.